# How to get Parameter names in ZF2 site's Index Controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Hi currently i am doing project in ZF2. In my project there are lot of folders in public directory. when any of visitor enter `www.domain.com/folder-name` it should redirect to that folder in public directory. in scenario how can i get that name of the folder name into one variable in site `IndexController`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear to me. When you call a sub-folder within `/public`, then depending on your `ReWrite-Rules`, you'll either get `403 Forbidden` or you'll get the `DirectoryIndex`. If you call a file, you'll see the file.

Either way, ZF2 isn't even running at that time.

What kind of variable do you want to have in your Controllers and for what purpose? Do you want to create something like a `DirectoryListing`?